# Java - Pattern matching strange behaviour

Tags: java, regex

I have to perform partial pattern matching, so I tested pattern matching against the following input

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("hello");
Matcher m = p.matcher("[a-z]");
```

Can anybody explains me why

```
System.out.println(m.find() || m.hitEnd());
```

prints `true` while

```
System.out.println(m.hitEnd());
```

prints `false`?

Comment: @BrianRoach: you're right, it's not really about pattern matching. The question is basically how the `hitEnd()` method works, which can be confusing. See my answer for details.

Comment: @stefano I hope it is intended by you, that the pattern is `hello`, and the input string is `[a-z]`. Because `[a-z]` looks like a regular expression, and `hello` like a input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this program:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("hello");
Matcher m = p.matcher("[a-z]");
System.out.println(m.hitEnd()); // prints false
System.out.println(m.find());  // prints false
System.out.println(m.hitEnd()); // prints true
```

Notice, the first call of `m.hitEnd()` returns `false`. Look at [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#hitEnd%28%29), it says:

> Returns true if the end of input was hit by the search engine **in the
>   last match operation performed by this matcher**.

Here it returns `false`, because it is called before the call of `m.find()`, so the matcher hasn't performed any match operations, yet. After the call of `m.find()` it returns `true` (because `find()` consumes the complete input string and *hits* the *end*). The meaning of that is also explained in JavaDoc:

> When this method returns true, then it is possible that more input
>   would have changed the result of the last search.

When this returns true, it means the matcher hit the end of the input. In this case, hit means reached, not matched. (The input was completely consumed by the matcher).

**EDIT**

I hope it is wanted by you, that `[a-z]` is the input string for your regular expression `hello`, and it's not the other way around. If you had

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]"); // The regex needs to be compiled.
Matcher m = p.matcher("hello");       // The input is given to the matcher
while (m.find()) {                    // In this case, returns true 5 times
    System.out.println(m.group() + ", ");
}
```

your output would be

```
h, e, l, l, o,
```

Comment: No it doesn't print what you (and I) expected. In the order it prints false, *false*, true. The find() method doesn't seem to work as expected, this is my probem.

Comment: @stefano: right, was a typo of mine ;) I never expected `find()` to be `true`. I definitely think you have the pattern and the input string mixed up. See my edit.

Comment: Ok, understood. Honestly, the doc is a little bit ambigous (at least for a non-eglish person). I swapped the parameters of Patter.compile(...) and Matcher.find(...).

Comment: So wait a second... does this mean my current solution is incorrect in context to this question? And the original was right? WE WILL GET THIS RIGHT EVENTUALLY, lol

Comment: @stefano: It actually makes sense. This way, you can compile a pattern once, and _feed_ it many input strings.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

Because `m.find()` itself processes the pattern fully, but does not find a match (and returns `false`). The pattern is fully consumed after this call, so `hitEnd()` will result `true`.

In the second call, the pattern is not consumed, so `hitEnd()` returns `false`.

For `hitEnd()` the Javadoc says:

> Returns true if the end of input was hit by the search engine in the last match operation performed by this matcher.

Reflecting on comment from @jlordo : Maybe you want to **change the pattern and the text**:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("hello");
```

because `"[a-z]"` rather looks like a pattern.

Comment: `m.find()` returns `false`, because the pattern `hello` cannot be found in the string `[a-z]`.

Comment: Yes, I removed my downvote. You are answering the question correct. But it doesn't solve OP's problem, he confused the regex with the input string.

Comment: @jlordo That's true, that was the misleading part... Interesting, but if we would change the pattern and the text (as probably the OP originally wished), we would get the same result... :)

Comment: Yes, if you read the comments below my answer, the OP says that he confused regex and input. I think the rest of the question is then obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(m.find() || m.hitEnd());
```

m.find() returns a boolean - that boolean is false. We just processed hit the end of input searching through - that makes m.hitend() result in true. false || true equates to true, accordingly.

The previous operation hit the end - hitend() returns true if..well, here's javadoc:

```
Returns true if the end of input was hit by the search engine in the last 
match operation performed by this matcher.
```

We DIDN'T reach the end...on the last operation. So hitend() is false. Successive calls would result in false.

Comment: `m.find()` returns `false`, because the pattern `hello` cannot be found in the string `[a-z]`.

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade: Why don't you upvote helpful questions and answers?

Comment: @jlordo I do, typically; I think my profile shows a pretty active vote record. I'll probably wait until this question is fully resolved to distribute my votes.

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade: Ok ;) I am more of a quick voter type :D

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade `m.find()` will always return `false`, as long as the pattern is `hello`! In our case (`Pattern.compile("hello");`) the pattern is `hello`. What you write only is good for `Pattern.compile("[a-z]");`

Comment: In the case of OP, `hitEnd()` will always return `false` prior to a call of `find()` and `true` after a call of `find()`, because `find()` will consume the complete input string (it's _end_ will be _hit_). I'll try to put that in my answer. Anyway, based on the comments below my answer, the OP confused the regex with the input string.